# Terraform - Ignore part of a variable's value if it equals a certain value

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, dynamic, conditional-statements, terraform

I am trying to create a multi-cloud solution for building out security rules for EC2/GCE instances. The idea is that I only want to use a *single* `.tfvars` file which works for both platforms.

Everything works, however, because of a discrepancy between AWS & GCP (AWS requires you to provide a port value of `-1` and GCP requires that you *don't* provide a port when defining an ICMP rule), my solution doesn't entirely work. Here's a snippet of my `.tfvars`:

```
rules = [
 {
    protocol = "tcp"
    port = 22
    cidrs = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  },
  {
    protocol = "icmp"
    port = -1
    cidrs = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  }
]
```

These are passed into `variables.tf`:

```
variable "rules" {
  type = list(object({
    protocol = string
    port = number
    cidrs = list(string)
  }))
}
```

Which are then accessed using dynamic blocks. Here's the example for GCP:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "this" {
  name        = "rule"
  network     = "network"
  project     = "project"
  target_tags = "targets"

  dynamic "allow" {
    for_each = var.rules

    content{
      protocol = allow.value["protocol"]
      ports    = [allow.value["port"]]
    }
  }
}
```

So essentially, I either need to tell the GCP module to *ignore* `allow.value["port"]` when it equals `-1`, or I need to not define the port for ICMP in my `.tfvars` file, and tell AWS to *add* `-1` as a port number when `allow.value["protocol"]` is equal to `icmp`.

Any suggestions on how to achieve either of these would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform 0.12, as well as introducing `dynamic` blocks, [introduced](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements) [`null`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#null) which will omit sending the attribute to the provider.

This works nicely when you have something [conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html) and the provider isn't happy with say an empty string to mean that it's being omitted (a common trick pre 0.12).

So for you you could do this:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "this" {
  name        = "rule"
  network     = "network"
  project     = "project"
  target_tags = "targets"

  dynamic "allow" {
    for_each = var.rules

    content{
      protocol = allow.value["protocol"]
      ports    = allow.value["port"] == -1 ? null : [allow.value["port"]]
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you set `port` to `-1` then it will omit the `ports` attribute from the `allow` block but otherwise it sets it to the value of the `rules.port`.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks @ydaetskcoR. I didn't realise you could use conditionals for a single argument like that, I had only seen them used at the top of a resource to decide on creating the entire thing!